# How can I automatically combine multiple Excel files with many sets into one file?

Tags: python, excel, loops

I was creating a program that loops through the process of combining three excel files into one file.

However, my program cannot copy the referenced sections in the files successfully. I had described the specific problem in # of the below program.

I would appreciate your help.

```
enter code here
```

## coding: UTF-8

from re import S
from typing import Counter
from numpy import longlong
from openpyxl.compat.strings import safe_string
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlwt
import openpyxl
import os
import pathlib
import datetime #import part is including all of sets for caluculation. some of code is not used in this code file

path = r'C:/Users/Files' #this code is counted number of excel_files in 'File'

directory = os.listdir(path)
counter=len(directory) #counted result. Now this number is about 700. we would use this code to another FY data.

for iii in range(1,counter+1): # file numafer of xx1, xx2 and xx3 are same
xx1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/imput1/result1_%s.xlsx'% iii) #caluculation result file type 1 (developed)
xx2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/imput2/result2_%s.xlsx'% iii) #caluculation result file type 2 (developed)
xx3 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/imput3/result3_%s.xlsx'% iii) #caluculation result file type 3 (developed)

```
xx1_distance=xx1["distance"]
xx1_P=xx1["P"]
xx1_Q=xx1["Q"]
xx1_W=xx1["W"]
xx1_a_collect=xx1["a_collect"]

xx2_ana=xx2["解析"] # result file type 2 is used Japanese on sheet names
xx2_kakei=xx2["家計"]
xx2_ka_moto=xx2["家計元データ"]
xx2_douro=xx2["道路面積"]
xx2_ins=xx2["焼却場"]

xx3_rate=xx3["Rate"]

#confirm each sheet number, these number are diffent by files
k=xx1_distance.max_column-1 
l=xx2_kakei.max_row 
m=xx2_kakei.max_column 
l3=xx3_rate.max_row 
m3=xx3_rate.max_column 

#increae sheet by k number
book = openpyxl.Workbook()

for i in (1,k+1):
    book.create_sheet() #sheet creation

sheet1 = book.worksheets[0]
sheet1.title = "facility_houseconsumption"

sheet={}
rate={}
kakei={}

for i in (1,k+1):
    ii=i
    ia= book.worksheets[i]
    ia.title = "facility_"+str(i)
    for a in (1,m+1):
        ia.cell(row=1, column=a+1).value =xx2_kakei.cell(row=1, column=a).value
    for j in (1,l+1): #this part don't be worked. For xample, l=10 and m=20, this code output only j=1 and a=1 result. I don't understand why this mistake is happened. 
        ia.cell(row=1, column=1).value ="rate"
        ia.cell(row=j+1, column=1).value =xx3_rate.cell(row=j+1, column=i+1).value
        for a in (1,m+1):
            ia.cell(row=j+1, column=a+1).value =xx2_kakei.cell(row=j+1, column=a).value
            rate[i,j]=ia.cell(row=j+1, column=1).value #this part is another caluculation variables
            kakei[i,j,a]=ia.cell(row=j+1, column=a+1).value #this part is another caluculation variables

book.save('C:/Users/output/output_%s.xlsx'% ii)
```

Comment: which part are you struggling with and what is the error ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I struggling this part. Detail is written by #.

    for j in (1,l+1): #this part don't be worked. For example, l=10 and m=20, this code output only j=1 and a=1 result. I don't understand why this mistake is happened.

Comment: `xx1` and `xx2` are not defined. presumably they are dictionaries or dataframes, but what are the values ?     users need to be able to replicate the problem in order to correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. These parts are not included code, but I wrote these definitions.
"for iii in range(1,counter+1): # file numafer of xx1, xx2 and xx3 are same xx1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/imput1/result1_%s.xlsx'% iii)"  xx1, xx2 and xx3 are input excel data from another results.